# Android notification white icon display for some device

Tags: android, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

I have used phone-gap push plugin for push notification, every things works find except icon display on device. white icon is display for notification on some device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add all your notification icon in below all directories

res/drawable-mdpi/ (24x24)

res/drawable-hdpi/ (36x36)

res/drawable-xhdpi/ (48x48)

res/drawable-xxhdpi/ (72x72)

res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ (96x96)

res/drawable-xxxhdpi/ (256x256)

- If you miss an icon size, it may not display correctly.
- If you see a solid square, you set the image correctly, but did not
  generate with transparency in the shape you want to show.
- If you see a white square in the preview on the page above you did
  not set the alpha channel correctly on your icon.
- you must be sure the icon filenames are correct.

**Small Icon**
If you prefer to create your own icons, you must make your icons the following size and colors:

Type    Size (px)
Small Notification Icon (mdpi)

24x24

Small Notification Icon (hdpi)

36x36

Small Notification Icon (xhdpi)

48x48

Small Notification Icon (xxhdpi)

72x72

Small Notification Icon (xxxhdpi)

96x96

**Other - Large Icon**
Type    Size (px)
Large Notification Icon (xxxhdpi)

256x256

Batter to use below tool to generate notification icon.
[Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_onesignal_default)